# Why does google separate out its sign in process to 2 pages now? Is that bad UX or just unconventional?

Tags: forms, login, ux-field

### Firstly:

[image]

### Enter my email address, then hit enter takes me to:

[image]

Feels like it's unnecessarily staggered, but maybe I'm missing something? This is a relatively new occurrence as well

Comment: microsoft do the same thing now if you try to go to the one drive website and log in there as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google [explained why they are doing this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/oAsE-6wmaSU):

> we're working towards introducing new authentication solutions that
>   complement traditional passwords

And later down in the blog:

> This new Google account sign-in flow will provide the following
>   advantages:
>
> - Preparation for future authentication solutions that complement passwords
> - **Reduced confusion among people who have multiple Google accounts**
> - A better experience for SAML SSO users, such as university students or corporate users that sign in with a different identity provider
>     than Google

It's hard to say what the "future authentication solutions" will be, but I think this is geared towards devices that have face recognition and/or fingerprint scanners.

There are some beneficial effects for the user, mainly the one in bold above. I use multiple Gmail accounts and I think this new layout simplifies logging in. The first page is an overall account manager with the ability to select an account, or add/delete an account.

[image]

Separating the password onto its own page avoids any confusion about which account you're singing into because it shows your picture (if on a familiar device) and email. Trying to cram all that functionality into one page could probably be done but separating seems cleaner.

Edit: I didn't realize this when posting, but this might be a duplicate. [See more thoughts here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78805/why-is-google-using-a-new-2-step-gmail-sign-in-process).

Comment: I guess I'm not sure still how this benefits the user but, as you say, if it's part of a broader move towards different authentication options then perhaps this is just a small change towards a new over all journey...but at the moment it just feels looking and pointless. I've upvoted for now.. could you maybe expand with anything relating to how this two-stage log in will benefit users?

Comment: I reworded it a little bit, didn't have too much to add but tried to make it clearer. Also added a link to a similar question I hadn't noticed before.