# Are there any science based studies on separating username and password in two screens?

Tags: accessibility, login

I was trying a similar approach to google which login in 1 page and password in the second but a coworker said that for accessibility reasons password and login should be in one screen. Is there any science-based evidence for this?

Comment: Have you looked at [why Google does that in the first place](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78805/why-is-google-using-a-new-2-step-gmail-sign-in-process)? It seems like the benefits summarized in [the top answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/78810/77811) might fit their use case, but not most services.

Comment: there are no accessibility issues with having the id/pw on the same page or separate pages provided they're labeled properly.

Comment: @slugolicious and also that the flow can be navigated with keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a heated debate but here is [Google's official explanation regarding why they separated username/password onto different pages for Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUoAsE-6wmaSU/?hl=en):

> This new Google account sign-in flow will provide the following advantages:
>
> - Preparation for future authentication solutions that complement passwords
> - Reduced confusion among people who have multiple Google accounts
> - A better experience for SAML SSO users, such as university students or corporate users that sign in with a different identity provider than Google

I could see separating UN/PW across different pages having **security** advantages, e.g., the system could theoretically offer more personalized security authentication (based on the email entered, offer an image or phrase specific to that email/user), then ask for password. But, no doubt, this security technique wouldn't be foolproof.

See [this Ghacks article](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/05/15/google-splits-sign-in-process-into-two-pages/) for more on this subject.

From a UX/usability standpoint, having the UN/PW on one page would likely be faster for the user, of course. Usability vs. security; there are always trade-offs to make. ;)